# Can I share VirtualBox+Ubuntu 12.04/Guest Additions with different OSes?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, ubuntu-12.04

I currently installed VirtualBox+Ubuntu/Guest Additions on OS X. Is it possible to share my vdi with A VirtualBox that is installed on Windows?

In other words, are the Guest Additions installed specifically geared for OS X, or are they specific for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that they consist of device drivers and system applications that optimise the guest operating system for better performance and usability. In your scenario they're specific to Ubuntu so you should be able to virtual machines. I guess if the hardware is vastly different (e.g. moving from AMD to Intel) then there may be problems.

The Virtuabox docs [here](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#idp11962400) talk in more detail about guest additions.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the virtual machines are not hardware specific and it should work fine for you. I have moved successfully several times a virtual box from one machine to a completely different hardware machine by simply exporting and importing the 'appliance' (you have that option in the menu). 
Granted although having completely different hardware, both machines were running Ubuntu, but different versions. However, the main Virtual Box layer should completely hide the true OS from the guest box, so it should work fine even between different operating systems.

So all you need to do is launch VM Virtual Box, select your guest virtual box (do not start it, just select it) and from the menu:
 
**File -> Export Appliance**
and follow the instructions. The guest virtual box will be saved in a compressed file on a destination of your choosing.

On the other machine, do the same but in the menu select:
**File -> Import Appliance**

and select the guest virtual box you prepared in the previous step.